# Having trouble loading tables in a conda environment after an apparently sucessful install

Tags: python, conda, pytables

I installed pytables in a conda environment following this [tutorial](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/installation.html) under the conda section. Basically I did the following steps:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install pytables
conda install hdf5
```

Now everything seems to be correctly installed, but there is the first possible issue. The following command in the tutorial would be `python setup.py install`. This threw me off, first because it seems to be already installed, and secondly because there is no setup.py file in my current directory and the tutorial doesn't make clear where it should be. Running it I obviously get

```
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

So I decided to assume this was from another way to install the package without conda and was somehow misplaced in the tutorial.

However, when I try to load the package with `import tables` I get

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0a99ad28a088> in <module>
    
----> 1 import tables

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tables\__init__.py in <module>
     97 
     98 # Necessary imports to get versions stored on the cython extension
---> 99 from .utilsextension import (
    100     get_pytables_version, get_hdf5_version, blosc_compressor_list,
    101     blosc_compcode_to_compname_ as blosc_compcode_to_compname,

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

If it is of any relevance, I'm trying to isntall it in Windows 10

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably not in the PyTables directory. Did you download the directory on you pc? After you download the binaries and cd to that directory you can continue the steps. If you're using windows 10 you probably also need Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, also on Windows, trying to load a `pandas.DataFrame` object saved in HDF5 format.

First, I was prompted an error trying to load the file: missing the `tables` optional dependency. I installed `pytables` in my `conda` environment with `conda install pytables`.

Then I got this same error message: `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

I found the solution on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/pytables-feedstock/issues/31). **The thread led me to install `snappy`** with `conda install snappy`, and all works fine.

I'm not sure this is the best solution (I suspect all this has nothing to do with `snappy` itself, rather with the path configuration or something like this); but this did fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I see where your confusion might stem from. I tried this out of curiosity to see if I could replicate your error and this is what I found:

Here are my steps:

open anaconda prompt

```
mkdir testdir
cd testdir
conda create --name testenvironment #Do this to make your life easier. Its good to work on virtual environments.
conda activate testenvironment #you can switch back later by doing conda deactivate

conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install pytables

#hdf5 should install automatically but in case it doesn't...
conda install hdf5
```

This is where your error comes in. You probably didn't install/didn't change directory (cd) to the pytables installation you created. Running `python setup.py install` here will cause your error.

I used Git to get the files but you might have to go with a different method.

```
git clone https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables.git

cd PyTables
python setup.py install
```

That should get you started. As noted in the comment above you need a C++ compiler to take this further on windows.
Good luck!

Comment: Now that is a weird thing. I created a new environment to follow your steps. Just for fun I decided to try loading tables before downloading anything from github. Guess what, it worked. So it works on a new environment, but not on the old one. Any clue why?

Comment: Maybe something got screwed up in your base environment when you were trying it out the first time or you had some package which was messing with your table installation? As long as something made it work its a victory...

Comment: The answer depends on what you did before the `python` command. For example, I use conda's base environment (no need to create a new one), and work in the Spyder IDE (starting from the Windows Program menu). No configuration is required. If you want to run from a command prompt, you have to configure the environment. To do this, you need to run the config command (it's `config_conda` on my system, with the PATH set to include the conda install folder). Once you do this, the `python`command will work. Copy `setup.py` to your folder, and you should be able to run.